# Error Install Doctrine-odm MongoDb in Symfony

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, odm

I have few problems with mongoDb and Symfony.
I installed php driver 1.6.12 and I want to install [mongoDbBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

add these lines in my composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0"
},
```

}

and Then

```
php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

But I Have these error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.1 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.2 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.3 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.4 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1].
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.2.1 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4].
```

Comment: Seems You haven"t the php mongo extension nstalled

Comment: Check the php.ini on the cli env

Comment: Don't forget to pick the right answer, this will help other people!

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, the `doctrine/mongodb-odm` dependency [requires mongo PHP extension](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/composer.json#L18) to be installed and enabled in your PHP installation.

You can check if you have it by looking into your `php.ini` file and/or on a page with `phpinfo()`. If it's not installed/enabled, you have to do it, otherwise you can't install those dependencies.

Comment: yes install mongodb server on your system is the resolution. To do so go here (tested) https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/